# How to fix onclick listener on ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

When I click .delete, and close the modal, then click another delete, then click #btn-submit, it send ajax 2 times. How to fix this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        //some code here
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            dataType:'xml',
            data:{
                data:'get_article',
                id:$(this).attr('article-id')
            },
            success:function(r){
                //some code here
                $(document).on('click', '#delete-modal #btn-submit', function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'ajax.php',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:{
                            data:'delete_article',
                            id:$(r).find('id').text()
                        },
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(r){
                            //some code here
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: In success call back every time .delete is clicked it attaches new event handler. So if you click .delete 2 times and click #btn-submit it will get called twice. If you click .delete 3 times it attaches another event. You need to check if event is not register only then attach it or you can take it out of success function and attach it when document loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but you definitely should NOT be attaching a click event listener in the success callback of the ajax function. It's probably attaching a new click event handler every time you send a POST request after clicking on the `.delete` class, resulting in multiple ajax requests going out when you click on a `.delete-modal` class. You should have your click listeners look something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    //some code here
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        cache:false,
        dataType:'xml',
        data:{
            data:'get_article',
            id:$(this).attr('article-id')
        },
        success:function(r){
            //some code here
            
        }
    });
});
$(document).on('click', '#delete-modal #btn-submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            data:'delete_article',
            id:$(r).find('id').text()
        },
        cache:false,
        success:function(r){
            //some code here
        }
    });
});
```